# EhCache/Hibernate configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I run JPA/Hibernate (hibernate-core-3.5.4, hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0, ehcache 2.4.3) and I  am realizing that I have configured ehcache using the old values (pre 3.3) as follows (in my persistence.xml) and this in production:

```
 <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
```

Will ehcache still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will, but you should switch to the newer style asap... This will lead to perf improvements.